# can't mirror remote PC's screen via HDMI cable when connecting with iPad Pro

Tags: windows-10, remote-desktop, ipad

I have bought a lightning hub for my iPad Pro. It has 3 inputs: HDMI, RJ45, and OTG (and, of course, charger input). There is no problem when mirroring its own screen to the projector device via this hub. But, when I remotely connect to my personal Windows Desktop PC (via RD client or Anydesk), the iPad's screen goes black, and only the projector shows the remote PC's screen. However, I want to see the PC's screen on the iPad too.

- iPad has iOS 16.6 (can't update further)
- Remote PC: Windows 10 Pro
- Both are on same LAN
- Used apps: RD Client (Microsoft), Anydesk.
- Used hub:
  https://www.amazon.com.be/-/en/Adapter-iPhone-Ethernet-Digital-Compatible/dp/B08ZMWD93V

Any idea how to fix it?